# I get "database is locked" errors on a read-only SqlCipher database

Tags: c, database, sqlite, sqlcipher

I have a single threaded application that only reads data from an encrypted SQLite database.  The encryption is accomplished with the [SqlCipher](https://www.zetetic.net/sqlcipher/) security extension.  This application does no writing to this database as it is for reference data only.  We run multiple copies of this application in parallel and all using the same database.  With two simultaneous copies we had no problem.  When we increased to eight copies we began to get consistent "database is locked" errors.  We were opening the database with the SQLITE_OPEN_READWRITE flag.  We switched to the SQLITE_OPEN_READONLY flag and observed no fewer errors.

This just doesn't seem right.  Why is there an exclusive database lock when there are no write operations at all?

Comment: Is it only with encrypted dbs? Have you tried on a regular db?

Comment: I have not yet tried it with an unencrypted version.  I will try that and report back.